# Detect if a thread is queued up / overworked

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

In Java I have a situation where many TCP connections (MINA) are creating work for a given thread and sometimes this thread becomes overworked, queued up and behind.  I am wondering a good way to monitor this within the process so that the application can reduce its workload when its threads get bogged down.  Essentially the only way I know to do this is to drop monitoring tasks on the thread and occasionally poll to see if they have been finished up but I feel there should be something more direct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the trick is to *not* queue up jobs for a thread but rather have a thread-pool that works on your tasks.  You then can better balance the number of thread working on your tasks.

You might want to set an initial number of threads but then grow it if the blocking queue fills up.  It is important to realize that the queue has to fill *before* the first thread past the initial size is allocated.  I know it's counter-intuitive but that's the way it works.

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(QUEUE_SIZE);
ExecutorService threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(NUM_INITIAL_THREADSs,
            MAX_NUM_THREADS, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
...
// submit the jobs...
// after submitting the jobs, you need to shutdown the queue
threadPool.shutdown();
```

As @Cratylus mentioned, you can bound your queue so that additional jobs will not be put into the queue unless there is room.   This slows the job producer but doesn't make things run faster.  After defining the thread-pool, you can set a rejection handler that will block the producer instead of throwing an exception.

```
threadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
       // this will block if the queue is full
       executor.getQueue().put(r);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly tasks are queued to be processed by a thread and you need a way to make sure that the queue does not grow indefinetely as workload increases while thread is not able to catch up.

You can use a bounded queue so that once the queue has reached capacity you know that the thread is not able to cope and you wait/reduce the workload (your OP is very abstract so my answer is from a bird's view as well)  until the queue starts to clear